# User_data in terraform unable to receive variable of pem key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

While creating ec2 instance with Terraform, I wish to inject the whole pem key file into the script.

```
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  ...
  user_data = base64encode(templatefile(
    "${path.module}/userdata.sh", {
       conf_tls_private_key = tls_private_key.mykey.private_key_pem
       conf_tls_self_signed_cert = tls_self_signed_cert.mykey2.cert_pem
    }
  ))
}
```

The terraform file implementation is as above. While using terraform console, I tested the `tls_private_key.mykey.private_key_pem` expression and it gives me the normal OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY format.

```
❯ tf console
> tls_private_key.boundary.private_key_pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAql5ImjYHynOkQGWL0DGT/3FGCIM6gouUi57MllyZCztzrBwp
FtWe+zJNWWjAu+WeyESqSnzmdFRnUiIqqo4Fq98yvF3+pjsbSMsC9s4H4wz/gp4o
ZzYXja4u7fBWGFMUKfU53M6zZS0FL0QQ/Tgt9u+p9q6HlyhtxiNKY0e3aX4xdCMH
QSrBLBIHLlpapkl/bvWk1xkSPEPNkNHbTvBd+3z2iWtxANEqO6ARItCCI+DcGyWP
W1FIwwKFBftNQAgxfs2pxdSnqpoaHSi4M9XjY7r7bADUItf9zpAy+PbqJr+F3Bzc
```

However, while the `userdata.sh` gets executed in ec2, it gives an error like below.

```
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 8: RSA: command not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 9: MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAql5ImjYHynOkQGWL0DGT/3FGCIM6gouUi57MllyZCztzrBwp: No such file or directory
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 10: FtWe+zJNWWjAu+WeyESqSnzmdFRnUiIqqo4Fq98yvF3+pjsbSMsC9s4H4wz/gp4o: No such file or directory
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 11: ZzYXja4u7fBWGFMUKfU53M6zZS0FL0QQ/Tgt9u+p9q6HlyhtxiNKY0e3aX4xdCMH: No such file or directory
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 12: QSrBLBIHLlpapkl/bvWk1xkSPEPNkNHbTvBd+3z2iWtxANEqO6ARItCCI+DcGyWP: No such file or directory
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 13: W1FIwwKFBftNQAgxfs2pxdSnqpoaHSi4M9XjY7r7bADUItf9zpAy+PbqJr+F3Bzc: command not found
```

It seems that each line in file is interpreted as a command, which is not I've intended.

The code in `userdata.sh` that caused the problem is as below.

```
echo $conf_tls_private_key | sudo tee "/etc/pki/tls/boundary/boundary.key"
```

Is there anything I'm unaware of or anything I can fix this problem? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would recommend checking the following version of the `userdata.sh` which uses [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

tee /etc/pki/tls/boundary/boundary.key << END
${conf_tls_private_key}
END
```

This should be more natural way of using `tee` to write multi-line strings to `/etc/pki/tls/boundary/boundary.key` and also output them to stdout.